# What does "chain-smoking grandmother" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "chain-smoking grandmother" mean? Is it an idioms?

> Jim had hated every second of it and the memories made him light another cigarette straight from the last. He would be turning into his **chain-smoking grandmother** if he wasn't careful.
>   [Musungu Jim and the Great Chief Tuloko](https://books.google.ae/books?id=3nkJCVKMMFgC)

Comment: A chain-smoker is a person who smokes one cigarette after another.

Comment: See usage examples here: https://www.google.it/search?q=%22chain+smoking%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2006,cd_max:2008,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&prmd=ivn&ei=8dngWNKUJeaIgAbnxonYCQ&start=0&sa=N&biw=768&bih=1004&dpr=2

Comment: To use **chain-smoking** adjectivally like that is relatively uncommon. Normally it is a noun (*he|she is a chain-smoker*) or a gerund (*chain-smoking is a sign of deep addiction.*) or a verb (*He|she's out in the alley, chain-smoking*.) I would consider the adjectival use ("his chain-smoking  grandmother") a literary one, rather like "pistol-packin' mama".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He refers to his grandmother who was a heavy smoker;

To [chain-smoke](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chain-smokers):

> - To smoke continually, as by lighting the next cigarette from the previous once. (First recorded in 1930-35.)

(AHD)

I can't find any evidence that chain-smoking is often used with grandmother/father. Actually [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chain-smoking%2Cchain-smoking%20grandmother%2Cchain-smoking%20grandfather&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchain%20-%20smoking%3B%2Cc0) shows no usage instances.

***[Chain smoking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_smoking)*** :

> - is the practice of smoking several cigarettes in succession, sometimes using the ember of a finished cigarette to light the next. Often the term chain smoker refers to a person who smokes relatively constantly, not necessarily chaining each cigarette. The term applies primarily to cigarettes, although it can be used to describe incessant cigar and pipe smoking as well. It is a common form of addiction.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Thank you, Why most of these expression used with grandmother (not grandfather)? e.g. I found the following in a technical article "Everyone and their chain-smoking grandmother knows that nicotine". http://www.bestclearomizer.com/ultimate-guide-to-diy-e-juice/

Comment: @Shannak - What makes you think it's used more often with *grandmother* than *grandfather*? Two instances hardly supports your case. E.g., I found the following in a book summary: "The narrator tells of his chain-smoking grandfather with the nicotine-stained eyebrow" [(link)](https://talkingbooks.osl.state.or.us//or1aopac/title/summary.jsf?id=118054650.7401). _Chain-smoking_ is simply an adjective and it can be used with [anyone](https://www.google.com/search?q="chain-smoking+cousin") who has the habit.

Comment: @J.R. Most of results on google are using "grandmother", and as I mentioned, I found it in some technical articles (not story about specific person)

Comment: @Shannak - Regardless of your perceived Google search results, I don't think there is any rhyme or reason. I think you're chasing a red herring, and you'll have to do more than cite a small handful of examples to convince me otherwise (and comments would not be the place to do that).

Comment: @AB - The phrase isn't found much on Ngrams, but you can find it in blogs and such. That said, it can be applied to any relative or acquaintance – aunts and uncles, brothers and sisters, neighbors and in-laws – as [this Google snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8tme.png) shows.